# Mysql counting number of occurrence rows different tables for same user

Tags: mysql

i have 2 different tables which user_id as common field.

how to write query to count total occurrence of each user in both tables.

say for example. there are 2 & 3 records for a user in two tables respectively. i need user id and total records (i.e) 5

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT userid FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userid FROM table2
)
WHERE userid = '123'
```

For all user*s*,

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT userid FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userid FROM table2
) t
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: then how to get for all user?  actually i need to get for all user whoever records are there in both tables

Comment: it says error "Every derived table must have its own alias" ? i am a new bee.